# SQL group type of query

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I am using SQL Developer and I have this table structure:

```
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)  
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)
```

What I want to do is print out the `department_id` which has **AT LEAST** 2 employees with salaries greater than 10000.

I though this would be the query

```
select department_id
from employees
having count(select * from employees where salary > 10000) > 2
group by department_id;
```

but, from what I found out, you can't put a SELECT statement inside COUNT so now I an stuck and I don't know how else am I supposed to do this query. Any suggestion is welcome.

UPDATE: Please note that I want **AT LEAST** 2 employees to have salary > 10000, not all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT  Department_Id, 
            COUNT(*)
      FROM  Employee
     WHERE  Salary > 10000
  GROUP BY  Department_Id
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63a9d/3)

Comment: seriously, please read the entire question before answering. If I wanted to check for everybody to have salary > 10000, your answer would be correct but I need AT LEAST two(ie, I have 4 employees in my department, 2 which have the salary greater than 10000 and another two with the salary smaller than 10000, this department_id is valid for what I need, and it is NOT valid for your query)

Comment: I have read the question.  See the example.  It returns what you have described.  There are 2 departments in the example with salaries below 10,000 (not returned), department 23 has 1 employee with salary over 10,000 (not returned) but the other with 2 employees having a salary over 10,000 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT department_id FROM employees
WHERE salary > 10000 GROUP BY department_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: no, that is wrong you check for everybody to have more than 10000 salary, I need AT LEAST 2

Comment: yes, that's what the GROUP BY department_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 part do. one thing to correct though, for at least 2, it should be HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2.